# Html page loaded by ajax doesn't display properly

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have js script which loads html page to div element of other html page:

Loaded page startScreen.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>asdf</p>
        <p>ablabablablabla</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JS function:

```
function setStartScreen(){

        var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'startScreen.html', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
            if (this.readyState!==4) return;
            if (this.status!==200) return;
            document.body.innerHTML= this.responseText;
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
```

When the script is loaded, it works - startScreen.html is loaded and connected with body. However it doesn't display properly. Two `<p>` tags are in the same line, and when I open startScreen.html separately in browser, they look correctly - one tag below another. I tried using additional `<br>` tag, but it doesn't work. Why is that happening, and how can I make it work properly?

Comment: Adding html/head/body inside the existing body probably isn't helping

Comment: Well, the first thing that comes to mind is that you're loading a complete HTML-page into a `<div>`, which breaks the page - you cannot have two `<!DOCTYPE>`-declarations, `<body>` and so on. Create the inclusion-page without all those extra elements, and see if it works then. (So just the `<p>`-elements in this case). If you need to be able to open the page by itself (with all the elements intact, you will have to parse the content and select what you need).

Comment: can you post the html of the page you are loading into?

Comment: Not very clean to add `html` tag into `body` tag. And maybe the 'local' css have a rule for `p` tags

Comment: I can't reproduce with `document.body.innerHTML = ...`. Probably it's because of your styles, which you didn't include. See [mcve], [ask], [tour].

Comment: Yes, Oriol was right, besides removing unnecessary tags, body had 'display: flex' style. I removed it and now it works. I apologize for dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `startScreen.html` shouldn't contain `html/head/body` tags, just the body content, e.g :

```
<p>asdf</p>
<p>ablabablablabla</p>
```

Else the page will have duplicated `tags` what make the page contain invalid HTML structure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but additional tags shouldn't make the paragraphs become inline.

Comment: @Oriol: It shouldn't once they remove the additional tags.  The additional tags was breaking the html code

Comment: @user1628733 The HTML parser must be able to recover from that error, unless the implementation has draconian error handling.